# C# OnDeserializing with Mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a quick question. Is it possible to use MongoDB with the OnDeserializing attribute or something like that?

```
MongoClient client { get; } = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var Userscollection = db.GetCollection<UserModel>("Users");
var userfind = (await Userscollection.FindAsync(x => x.UserId == "UserId"));
var user = userfind.FirstOrDefault();
```

My UserModel class has a function with the OnDeserializing attribute but it doesn't fire on Find and fetching the item of the user.

```
[OnDeserializing]
void TestFunc(StreamingContext context)
{

}
```

Is there any way to fire it automatically or any similar method to detect in the constructor of the class if the class is creating by my codes or using the MongoDB serializer/deserializer?

Comment: I also tried to create 2 constructors, One without any parameter witch used for deserializer and another for my own usage in codes. Unfortunately, even after calling the Constructor without any parameters, All of my class properties are having their default values exactly after the constructor code running ends, Properties are starting to set their values! So also using 2 constructors is not a possible way for my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, After poking a lot with attributes and lots of tries finally I found a solution for my case.
I commented above that creating 2 constructors doesn't work because settings values are going to be done after running constructors.
But, There's a workaround! BsonConstructor Attribute
create a simple constructor or with arguments for your own (if you need otherwise you can skip it)
Then create another constructor but using the BsonConstructor attribute like below.

```
[BsonConstructor()]
public Postmodel(ObjectId postid, ObjectId userid)
{
    //Called by the BSon Serialize/Deserialize
}
```

But surely this constructor will not be what you need because all of the properties are null or having default values so you need to pass some argument too.
The sample below will give you the values of properties you need so you can do whatever you want in the constructor.

```
[BsonConstructor(nameof(Id), nameof(UserId))]
public Postmodel(ObjectId postid, ObjectId userid)
{
}
```

Id and UserId are two properties in my class.
You can also simply use

```
[BsonConstructor("Id", "UserId")]
```

instead, But be careful, Changing properties name or removing them in the development won't notify you to fix your values, so using `nameof(PropertyName)` is much safer.